# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager to main queue

Tags: afnetworking

How can I run following code along with the main queue, so that I can handle URL response first?

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        [self method];
        **// can I manipulate the response here?**
        NSLog(@"Testing....");
    }

- (void)method {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [operationManager POST:@"http://test.com"
                parameters:@{@"test1":@"AU", @"test2":@"1"}
                   success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                       NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
                   }
                   failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                       NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
                   }
     ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the block versions of AFHTTPRequestOperationManager:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

self.getActSuccess = ^ (id responseObject)
{
    __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    // you can run following code
    [strongSelf.view XXXXX];
}

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[operationManager POST:@"http://test.com"
            parameters:nil
               success:self.getActSuccess
               failure:nil
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) Declare block in Header file [ViewController.h] as below.

`typedef void (^ResponseBlock)(BOOL success, id result, NSError *error);`

(2) Create your method with block as argument as below.

```
 - (void)method:(ResponseBlock)completionHandler {
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        [operationManager POST:@"http://test.com"
                    parameters:@{@"test1":@"AU", @"test2":@"1"}
                       success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                           NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
                           completionHandler(YES,responseObject,nil);
                       }
                       failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                           NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
                           completionHandler(NO,nil,error);
                       }
         ];
}
```

(3) Call method as below in your viewDidLoad.

```
 [self method: ^(BOOL success, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (success) {
        //Do your success task
    }
    else {
        //Else handle error
        NSLog(@"Error %@",error.localizedDescription);
    }
```

Comment: This has the same result. 'Testing....' has been logged first than the response JSON. I want to handle JSON response before 'NSLog(@"Testing....");'

Comment: @Raman Basically it will take some time to get response from any URL call so you have to handle wait until you get the response. And once you get the response continue your task in success block after "Do your success task".